# Kotlin and RxJava2 zip operator - None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, android-studio-3.0

I have a problem with writing the .zip Observable in Kotlin using Android Studio 3.0 IDE.

Here is my code:

```
internal var updateStringEventsSubject = PublishSubject.create<String>()
internal var updateIntEventsSubject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

internal var triggerSave = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()
internal var triggerStopAndSave = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()

internal var normalSaveTrigger = triggerSave.debounce(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
internal var trigger = Observable.merge(normalSaveTrigger, triggerStopAndSave)

private fun saveEvents(
        strings: List<String>,
        integers: List<Int>,
        someBoolean: Boolean): Boolean {

    return true //doesn't matter for now
}

fun temp() {
    Observable.zip<List<String>, List<Int>, Boolean, Boolean>(updateStringEventsSubject.buffer(trigger),
            updateIntEventsSubject.buffer(trigger),
            trigger, { strings: List<String>, integers: List<Int>, someBoolean: Boolean -> saveEvents(strings, integers, someBoolean) })
            .subscribe()
}
```

However, my IDE(Android Studio 3.0 RC2) underlines the .zip operator and says:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
>   zip(((observer: Observer!>) → Unit)!, ((observer: Observer!>) → Unit)!, ((observer: Observer) → Unit)!, ((t1: List, t2: List, t3: Boolean) → Boolean)!)   where T1 = List, T2 = List, T3 = Boolean, R = Boolean for    fun  zip(source1: ((observer: Observer) → Unit)!, source2: ((observer: Observer) → Unit)!, source3: ((observer: Observer) → Unit)!, zipper: ((t1: T1, t2: T2, t3: T3) → R)!): Observable! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
>   zip(((observer: Observer!>) → Unit)!, ((observer: Observer!>) → Unit)!, ((t1: List, t2: List) → Boolean)!, Boolean)   where T1 = List, T2 = List, R = Boolean for    fun  zip(source1: ((observer: Observer) → Unit)!, source2: ((observer: Observer) → Unit)!, zipper: ((t1: T1, t2: T2) → R)!, delayError: Boolean): Observable! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
>   zip(ObservableSource!>!, ObservableSource!>!, ObservableSource!, io.reactivex.functions.Function3!, in List!, in Boolean!, out Boolean!>!)   where T1 = List, T2 = List, T3 = Boolean, R = Boolean for    fun  zip(source1: ObservableSource!, source2: ObservableSource!, source3: ObservableSource!, zipper: Function3!): Observable! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
>   zip(ObservableSource!>!, ObservableSource!>!, BiFunction!, in List!, out Boolean!>!, Boolean)   where T1 = List, T2 = List, R = Boolean for    fun  zip(source1: ObservableSource!, source2: ObservableSource!, zipper: BiFunction!, delayError: Boolean): Observable! defined in io.reactivex.Observable

How to make it work with Kotlin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason using RxJava 1.1.7 it considers explicitly specifying the type of zipper argument as Func3 a redundant SAM-constructor (which it is) and allows you to replace it with a lambda. However, using RxJava 2.1.5 the type changes to Function3 and it no longer recognises it as an interface with a single abstract method (which it still is). I'm not sure why that is.

Regardless, specifying the type of the zipper function will do the trick:

```
import io.reactivex.functions.Function3
...

fun temp() {
    Observable.zip<List<String>, List<Int>, Boolean, Boolean>(updateStringEventsSubject.buffer(trigger),
            updateIntEventsSubject.buffer(trigger),
            trigger, Function3 { strings, integers, someBoolean -> saveEvents(strings, integers, someBoolean) } )
            .subscribe()
}
```

Note: I managed to get it to work without explicitly specifying the type arguments for `Function3`. It may depend on which version of Kotlin or RxJava you're using as to whether it can infer the types. If not you can always be more explicit:

```
Function3<List<String>, List<Int>, Boolean, Boolean> { ... }
```

**Edit:** There's an even easier way: Use `io.reactivex.rxkotlin.Observables` instead. It's an inline function that does the ugly type declaration under the hood for us. Then you can just do this:

```
import io.reactivex.rxkotlin.Observables
...

Observables.zip(updateStringEventsSubject.buffer(trigger),
                updateIntEventsSubject.buffer(trigger),
                trigger, 
                ::saveEvents)
```

Comment: This issue might be of interest "Dealing with necessary SAM adapters with RxJava2" https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin/issues/103

Comment: Can you post the whole statement? (the whole temp() method from my question)I am afraid it doesn't work

Comment: Updated to include the whole temp method @okset

Comment: Thanks, i also tried this but not worked. What worked for me was this: Function3<List<String>, List<Int>, Boolean, Boolean> { t1, t2, t3 ->
                    saveEvents(t1, t2, t3)

Comment: I'll update the answer to what worked for you. It may depend on the version of Kotlin as to whether the explicit type arguments are required

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Joeleski I found a bug. In my case I *specified type explicitly* to every parameter of a `zip` operator, then found that one variable had a wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

For who it may concern....

I had this issue when trying to execute `Observable.merge()`

The solution was changing it to `Observable.mergeArray()`